# Change UISearchBar width from right point

Tags: ios, animation, width, anchor

I have UISearchBar and I want it to expand on tap. I have animation like :

```
[UISearchBar beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
[UISearchBar setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut];
[UISearchBar setAnimationDuration:0.5];
[self.searchBar setFrame:CGRectMake(self.searchBar.frame.origin.x, self.searchBar.frame.origin.y, self.searchBar.frame.size.width +100, self.searchBar.frame.size.height)];
[UISearchBar commitAnimations];
```

This is working, but it expand it from left ro right, but I want it to expand it from right to left. I would like to do something like in the interface builder where you can choose 1 from 9 point from where it will expand.

I try to set

```
[searchBar.layer setAnchorPoint:CGPointMake(1, 0.5)];
```

but it didn't work.

Marko

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do the following:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.5
                 animations:^{
                     [UIView animateWithDuration:1.0 animations:^{
                         self.searchBar.frame = CGRectMake(self.searchBar.frame.origin.x - 50.0f, self.searchBar.frame.origin.y, self.searchBar.frame.size.width + 50.0f, self.searchBar.frame.size.height);
                         [self.searchBar layoutSubviews];
                     }];
                 }
                 completion:^(BOOL finished){  }];
```

This will make the right side stick and see the growth to the left side.

Comment: duration value has en error should be `0.5f` instead `0.5.f;`

Answer (score 0):

You should also change the origin of the UISearchBar in order get the desired effect. For example:
`self.searchBar.frame = CGRectMake(self.searchBa.frame.origin.x - YOUR_OFFSET, self.searchBa.frame.origin.y, self.searchBa.frame.size.width + YOUR_OFFSET, self.searchBa.frame.size.height)`.

Comment: No I try that and is not ok, because it animate weird.